# 2sxc - One content-type, one list view, one cshtml, some rows not shown

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dotnetnuke-9

Using 2sxc to create a new app with only:
- One content type
- 15 rows of data
- One view (razor, single cshtml file)

When I call the @foreach loop, only some of the data is shown in the list view (apparently the ones inserted in the current dnn module and only through the "new" button in the toolbar). If I add the row in the admin panel, it will not show. When I deleted the module and inserted it again, I can see the data in the admin panel, but not in my list view.

Attached screens.

I tried calling the data with:

```
@foreach(var Content in AsDynamic(Data["Default"])){...}
```

or

```
@foreach(var e in List.OrderBy(e => e.Content.Farmaco).Where(e => e.Content.Cat == "1")){
var Content = e.Content;
... }
```

but the result is the same.

Am I missing something really obvious?

DNN 9.1.1
2sxc 9.04.01

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4bmuuNWVx2MUxxa0g1SExqUkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the default setting for lists only pulls items for that module.  If you want to pull all items across the portal you will have to create your own query.  Once you have done that you can assign that query to your view. see this: https://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Visual-Query-Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're clearly not familiar yet with "raw data" and items-assigned to a modules.

In our code you get the module-data with Data["Default"], whereas the raw-data you would get from a query (then also with Data["Default"] or Data["Whatever-Name-Your-Stream-In-Your-Query"])

If you want to work with **all** data, you would again use a query, or App.Data["TypeName"] and build on that.

Check out http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/12-differences-when-templating-data-instead-of-content

Comment: Thanks. App.Data["TypeName"] worked perfectly.
How can I change the location (module for example) of each row of data?

Comment: each content-item can be used many times - so it's not assigned just to one place. this is something you'll have to discover as you start working with content in the more classic content-mode

Comment: Thanks again @iJungleBoy . These WIPs [here](https://servicodeurgencia.pt/Centro-de-conhecimento/10-F%C3%A1rmacos/107-C%C3%A1lculos-de-f%C3%A1rmacos-por-peso) and [here](https://servicodeurgencia.pt/Forma%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Casos-cl%C3%ADnicos) were only possible thanks to 2sxc and your help. Still a long way to go, but I'll make it.

Comment: Very cool - glad we could help :)
And please give back, by sharing your experience with others :)